# Compatibility between AppCompat and Androidx

Tags: android, material-design, androidx, android-datepicker, material-components-android

I need to create a DatePeriodPicker from my fragment like the following:

[image]

To create a date period dialog, I need to use the method .show();
in this method, I need to pass a fragmentManager.

```
                DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        Fragment_Details.this,
                        1999,
                        3-1,
                        2,2000,2-1,3
                );
                dpd.setYearRange(2000,2020);
                Calendar max_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                dpd.setMaxDate(max_calendar);
                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(),"P")
```

My project has been migrated to androidX, so whenever I pass a fragment manager, it passes an androidx fragment manager:(from my project)

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

however, the method .show() that is located in side a class in the library I am trying to use uses this import:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

I tried creating a java class, extending appcompat activity and passing fragmentmanager(android.app.Fragment)  to the method .show(). the method recognised that the fragment manager is from (AppCompat) however it could it crashed right after I created a new instance of this class from my fragment.

this Is my log when it crashes:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@13a430d[PopupWindow:c0edac8]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/AbsListView: onTouchUp() mTouchMode : 0
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mybimpos, PID: 19385
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1901)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:688)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:646)
        at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:233)
        at com.example.mybimpos.Dialog_attemp_2.<init>(Dialog_attemp_2.java:17)
        at com.example.mybimpos.Fragment_Reports_Details$2.onItemSelected(Fragment_Reports_Details.java:802)
        at org.angmarch.views.NiceSpinner$2.onItemClick(NiceSpinner.java:177)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:350)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1683)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4094)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$10.run(AbsListView.java:6583)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

this is the class I created to try to pass an appcompat fragment manager:

```
public class Dialog_attemp_2 extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    public Dialog_attemp_2() {
        DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                Dialog_attemp_2.this,
                1999,
                3-1,
                2,2000,2-1,3
        );
        dpd.setYearRange(2000,2020);
        Calendar max_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dpd.setMaxDate(max_calendar);
        dpd.show(getFragmentManager(),"pierre");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int yearEnd, int monthOfYearEnd, int dayOfMonthEnd) {

    }

}
```

I call this class from my fragment using:

```
new Dialog_attemp_2();
```

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: you should enable jetifier

Comment: I already have jetifier enabled: android.enableJetifier=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With androidx you can define a [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment.html) with an instance of [`DatePickerDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html)

```
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

and the call it with:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

**OPTION 2: new Material Component**

With the [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Picker.md) you can use the new `MaterialDatePicker`.

Currently it is under active development and requires version **1.1.0** of material components for android library.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

To select a **single date** just use:

```
       MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
       builder.setTitleText(R.string.your_text);
       MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();
       picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

To select a **range date** you can use a DateRange Picker using:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Pair<Long, Long>> builder =
                    MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
                CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();                                        builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build());
                MaterialDatePicker<?> picker = builder.build();
                picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

[image]

Comment: hello your method works but I wasn't Clear In my post. the class DatePeriodDialog is from a library and I have posted a picture of the dialog that I get from using it. so in my case android's date picker can't be of use to me because I need to have a period picker and not just a date picker.

Comment: @PierreKhoury Sorry my bad, didn't notice that. In that case you should check if DatePeriodPicker library supports androidx. In any case I've just added a new snippet because the new material component supports also a range picker.

Comment: it does support androidx! I I happen to like it's look and feel very much. thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use this fragmentmanager you can add app compat dependency

Add the gradle dependency:

```
"implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'"
```

And extend your activity from AppCompatActivity. And then change getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: I tried this, I changed the getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager() in my Dialog_attemp_2 java class. However when when I was passing getSupportFragmentManager() to the .show() method, I was getting this error: Cannot Resolve method 'show(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)

Comment: With AppCompatActivity?