# Changing the color of datepicker in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I tried some suggestion from [How to change DatePicker dialog color for Android 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/how-to-change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0) but the only problem is next the two of the buttons are not visible as after writing the code

```
public static void showExpenseDate(final Context context, final EditText textView) {

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                //String[] mons = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH).getShortMonths();
                //String mName = mons[monthOfYear];
                expense_date = String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf((monthOfYear + 1))
                        + "-" + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                textView.setText(expense_date);
                Log.d("djkjiksd", expense_date);

            }
        }, yy, mm, dd);

        datePicker.show();
    }
```

where as in theme.xml

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_yellow</item>
</style>
```

[image]

but the button colors are not coming on UI. What is the solution and correct way to implement date picker theme according to application.

Comment: using dialog right is painfulll (especially on activity recreation) ... use fragment like `AppCompatDialogFragment`

Comment: I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/ed73544da79022634a38e288d7a13088) 

like `DatePicker.newInstance(SOME_ID_TO_CHECK_IN_CALLBACK_ONACTION, someCalendar).show(get(Child)FragmentManager())`  and implementation of Callback like `public boolean onAction(int ID, boolean canceled, Calendar date) {
        final TextView textView;
        if (ID == SOME_ID_TO_CHECK_IN_CALLBACK_ONACTION) {
            if (!canceled) {
            /*do the staff*/
     }
     return true;
        }
 return false;
    }`

Comment: Switching to `MaterialDatePicker` is an option? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605124/compatibility-between-appcompat-and-androidx/57605698#57605698

Comment: `MaterialDatePicker` is somehow bummer (state on 2022-12)... it losing callbacks on recreate(fx orientation changed) ... they did a good job with `registerForActivityResult` and it's working fine  I would expect to `MaterialDatePicker ` work in similar way

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your style.xml file

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/yourColor</item>
    </style>
```

And then add this style while creating the DatePickerDialog

```
DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    
}
```

Comment: I did try this one, the only problem was a button was not of the same color also was not visible so I got the solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50771927/12637592

Answer (score 1):

**Modify your theme.xml something like this -**

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_yellow</item>
       <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/light_yellow</item>
       <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyled</item>
       <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyled</item>
       <item name="android:buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyled</item>
    </style>
    
    <style name="DialogButtonStyled" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Still not showing button ok, cancel. Is there some other way to resolve this?

Comment: I have modified answer please check, hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `MaterialComponents` theme in your app use this theme overlay for your `DatePickerDialog`:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Dialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/red500_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blu500_dark</item> <!-- button text color -->
</style>
```

If you  are using an `AppCompat` theme:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red500_light</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyled</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyled</item>
</style>
<style name="DialogButtonStyled" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blu500_dark</item> <!-- button text color -->
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: This works for me hopefully this will help others]

> the theme code still there in XML this code works for button color setting

[image]